# How to apply patch file to views module in Drupal 7

Tags: views

I have problem with my views module. In some occasions it displays this deterrent warning:

**Notice: Undefined property: views_handler_field_field::$original_value in views_handler_field->render_text() (line 1118 of C:\wamp\www\novine\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_field.inc).**

I think I found the patch that could work and save me from this buggy thing. My problem is how to apply downloaded patch to views module. I placed patch file in views folder, cached site, and  nothing happened. That was obviously naive try. 
Can someone help me and tell all applying patch procedure? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If it is a standard Drupal patch, you use a program named *git* (part of ambience in most Gnu/Linux configurations) to apply it.  The correct procedure is to first clone the newest released version of the project, apply the patch, then install the patched version in the views folder.  If the patch file is named `views-bugfix.patch` you download it, and then:

```
git clone --recursive --branch 7.x-3.x http://git.drupal.org/project/views.git
git apply -v views-bugfix.patch
```

In some cases, the patch is not for the released branch, but some other branch (this will be mentioned along with the patch).  In that case you need to clone this branch instead.

[Source for this info](http://drupal.org/project/views/git-instructions).

If you're stuck in a Microsoft environment and don't have *git* here is something that may help you: [Patching in Windows](http://drupal.org/node/620014) (haven't tested this myself - I don't do windows.)

Comment: Thank you, very much. I am going to investigate this in detail.